# Screen become blank after custom view transition

Tags: ios

I'm learning how to implement custom view transition. I want to create a slide menu something like spotify side menu. I'm using `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning`. The animation seems to be working but after dismissing transition, the screen become blank.

This is the code for presenting transition

```
#import "Transition.h"

@implementation Transition

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{
return 1;
}

-(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{

UIViewController *to=[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];
UIViewController *from=[transitionContext viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];

UIView *containerView=[transitionContext containerView];
to.view.alpha=0.0;


[containerView addSubview:to.view];
[containerView addSubview:from.view];

[UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContext] animations:^{
    from.view.frame = CGRectMake(200, 0, from.view.frame.size.width, from.view.frame.size.height);
    from.view.alpha=1.0;
    to.view.alpha=1.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [transitionContext completeTransition:YES];
}];

}
@end
```

This is the code for dismissal transition

```
#import "DismissTransition.h"

@implementation DismissTransition

- (NSTimeInterval)transitionDuration:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContext{
return 1;
}

-(void)animateTransition:(id<UIViewControllerContextTransitioning>)transitionContex{

UIViewController *from=[transitionContex viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextFromViewControllerKey];
UIViewController *to=[transitionContex viewControllerForKey:UITransitionContextToViewControllerKey];

UIView *containerView=[transitionContex containerView];


[UIView animateWithDuration:[self transitionDuration:transitionContex] animations:^{
    to.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, from.view.frame.size.width, from.view.frame.size.height);
    to.view.alpha=1.0;
    from.view.alpha=0.0;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    [transitionContex completeTransition:YES];
}];

}
@end
```

This is where my custom transition is called

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "Transition.h"
#import "DismissTransition.h"
#import "MenuViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()<UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate>

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (IBAction)buttonTap:(id)sender {
UIStoryboard *mystoryboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
MenuViewController* viewController = [mystoryboard  instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"MenuVC"];


viewController.modalPresentationStyle=UIModalPresentationCustom;
viewController.transitioningDelegate=self;

[self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForPresentedController:(UIViewController *)presented
                                                              presentingController:(UIViewController *)presenting
                                                                  sourceController:(UIViewController *)source{

return [[Transition alloc]init];
}

- (id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationControllerForDismissedController:(UIViewController *)dismissed{

return [[DismissTransition alloc]init];
}



@end
```

And this is how I dismiss MenuViewController

```
#import "MenuViewController.h"

@interface MenuViewController ()

@end

@implementation MenuViewController
- (IBAction)doneButtonTap:(id)sender {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
// Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



@end
```

Comment: I'm supposing you're developing on the iOS 8 SDK, so check the discussion on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588617/ios-8-screen-blank-after-dismissing-view-controller-with-custom-presentation and the answer by DJSK

Comment: Yes, I've already seen your answer. But my problem is that i need to present both presenting view and presented view at the same time. So, it can make an effect, a slide menu view appear from left of original view. So I need to add fromview into the container, otherwise, fromview will move to right, fade in and disappear. I doubt there might be problem in the menu view dismissing. And i am also not very sure if this is the right approach to create this effect.

Answer (score 0):

You should add to.view to containerView in DismissTransition