# Custom UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning shows black screen when finished

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, swift4

I have a segue, that is triggered via a button that shows another view controller modally over current context. I'm using a custom class to customize the transition, which is this:

```
class ShowAnimator: NSObject {
}


extension ShowAnimator: UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning {
func transitionDuration(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning?) -> TimeInterval {
    return 0.5
}
func animateTransition(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    guard
        let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from),
        let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to) else {
            return
    }
    let containerView = transitionContext.containerView
    containerView.insertSubview(fromVC.view, belowSubview: toVC.view)
    let toFrame = transitionContext.finalFrame(for: toVC)
    let screenBounds = UIScreen.main.bounds
    let bottomLeftCorner = CGPoint(x: screenBounds.width, y: 0)
    let finalFrame = CGRect(origin: bottomLeftCorner, size: screenBounds.size)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: transitionDuration(using: transitionContext),
                   animations: {
                    fromVC.view.frame = finalFrame
    },
                   completion: { _ in
                    transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    }
    )
}
}
```

In my main view controller, I have these relevant functions:

```
let showAnimator = ShowAnimator()
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let destination = segue.destination
    destination.transitioningDelegate = self
}


func animationController(forDismissed dismissed: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return nil
}
func animationController(forPresented presented: UIViewController, presenting: UIViewController, source: UIViewController) -> UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning? {
    return showAnimator
}
```

Note that this class is a ViewController as well as a `UIViewControllerTransitioningDelegate`
However, whenever I press the button to perform my segue, it does the animation properly, but once it's finished it just shows a black screen, rather than the next ViewController.

Comment: Here's a really good answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25588617/ios-8-screen-blank-after-dismissing-view-controller-with-custom-presentation

Answer (score 6):

One problem is this line:

```
containerView.insertSubview(fromVC.view, belowSubview: toVC.view)
```

You are inserting the `fromVC` view. That is wrong. It is already present (though not necessarily in the container).

And you are *not* inserting the `toVC` view. That is also wrong. You need to put it into the container.

Comment: I added:

    `containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)
        containerView.insertSubview(fromVC.view, aboveSubview: toVC.view)`

but now when I dismiss the view controller that was presented modally the screen goes black. Can you show me what to do?

Comment: Have we fixed the original problem, i.e. the black screen on presentation?

Comment: Yes, but when I dismiss the ViewController that was presented modally, it shows a black screen

Comment: I'm still confused. The problem posed was: "However, whenever I press the button to perform my segue, it does the animation properly, but once it's finished it just shows a black screen, rather than the next ViewController." Did we solve that problem? Are we now showing "the next ViewController"?

Comment: Ok, so let me try to explain what's happening now. When I press the button, it does the animation properly and shows the right ViewController. However, once that is dismissed, it shows a black screen, rather than the original viewcontroller. Maybe it has something to do with `animationController(for: dimissed`?

Comment: Okay, but let me emphasize the point I'm asking you about. You posed a particular problem. I tried to solve it. Did I? If so, the case is closed and you now have a _different_ problem. I don't know what you're doing now, and I can't be responsible for that. (Judging by your comment, you didn't read my answer very carefully and you're still doing this wrong, inserting the `fromVC.view` when you are not supposed to.)

Comment: Yes my problem went away, but it just made a new problem, which means I didn't get a sufficient answer, and I still need help with this issue. From what I understand from your answer, I should do `containerView.addSubview(toVC.view)` (adding toVC into the container), but what else?

Comment: Nothing else. Your job is to add the `toVC.view` to the container and that's all. Then just animate it into place. Done.