# Swipe up UITableView from bottom

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, mkmapview

I would really like to do this with a MapView as background, and a TableView a foreground: http://youtu.be/ZrZ_B7DRqdo . Does anybody know a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend following this [tutorial](http://www.teehanlax.com/blog/custom-uiviewcontroller-transitions/) but be **aware**, there is an underlying bug in iOS8 using this solution which you can solve easily like others did in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338700/from-view-controller-disappears-using-uiviewcontrollercontexttransitioning).

Another possibility is using `SCStackViewControllers` library available in [github](https://github.com/stefanceriu/SCStackViewController) which will provide multiple examples on how to stack and animate transitions between multiple `UIViewcontroller`.