# Why does UIViewControllerContextTransitioning return optionals?

Tags: ios, swift, custom-transition

When is it possible for this method of `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning` to return nil?

```
viewController(forKey key: UITransitionContextViewControllerKey) -> UIViewController?` method of `UIViewControllerContextTransitioning
```

If it is possible, how should you handle that? Can you somehow default to the system transition if you can't retrieve a view controller involved in the animation? I've been assuming that force unwrapping these values is safe.

Comment: I always force unwrap them.

Comment: Going to keep force unwrapping them, I've never gotten nil from this method in Obj-C or Swift. I suppose that's theoretically possible that the from/to VC could be nil'd out for some awful reason in the middle of a transitioning. And it looks like from here that there was a bug that was causing that to happen. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24338700/from-view-controller-disappears-using-uiviewcontrollercontexttransitioning But I think that even if it definitely wasn't possible, this API prob isn't pure Swift so it has to return an optional

Answer (score 0):

If you read the docs on that call, they say:

> Return Value
>
> The view controller object for the specified key or nil if the view
>   controller could not be found.

So if there is no view controller object for the specified key you'll get nil.

Comment: But the question is: in practice, does that ever happen? And if so, how could it?